# SSRS Parameter "Is Equal to all"

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, filter

Imagine a cube with two dimensions: `Car` and `Option`. `CarOptions` would be a measure.

[image: Cube]

Now lets imagine a report working on this cube.

The report displays the car name along with its options.

[image: Report]

On this report we have a parameter to filter on options.

When the user select two options I want to display cars which are linked to those two options.

For example if the user select ABS & GPS, no cars are displayed. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you using a parse function to pass the multi select list?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by 'parse function'. I use a data set to fill the Option parameter with values from the Option dimension. I have another data set whish is used by the report. In this data set I want to filter the car if the car does not match all the selected options.